# Modx Revo Articles not showing in manager anymore

Tags: php, mysql, modx-revolution

So the manager have decided to not show my articles that were/are in my Articles container anymore. They show up on the frontend and therefore obviously also in the db, but not in the manager. I can create new ones and they show up in the db but not the manager.

What I've done to try to solve this:

Upgraded modx to latest 2.3.3 from 2.2. 
Updated all extras to latest versions (Articles 1.7.11). 
Uninstalled and reinstalled Articles and its related extras. 
Repair the db in phpMyadmin

Anyone know what the problem can be?

Comment: you cleared both browser & modx cache [actually deleted the contents of /core/cache/ folder]?  are you using any sort of CDN that could be caching as well?

Answer (score 0):

Have (and had) the same problem on an modx-installation:
- modx: 2.2.16
- Articles: 1.7.3
- Quip: 2.3.3

Seems to be the content in either the field "introtext" or "content" in the table "site_content". 
Search for the latest entry, empty the "content" and/or the "introtext" field. 
Clear the cache in modx. The articles should show up again.

I never found out what kind of character, symbol or whatever combination of them causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this Problem is the "character setting" and "collation" of the Database. The recommended character set and collation for MODX is **utf-8** and **utf8_general_ci**.

In most cases the default setting for a new Database in mySQL is **Latin1 / latin1_swedish_ci**. Modx can work with this setting if you don't use any special characters in your content. But if you enter an accented character that doesn't play well with Latin1 it can cause the described problem.

**Solution:**
So the best way to avoid this problems is to set the Database to UTF-8 / uff_general_ci! I am not sure if the Database collation settings can be converted without crashing the whole system but I will try this today. I can give feedback if somebody is interested.

Comment: How did it go? I just tried it and I haven't seen any difference. Articles show on website, but not in the manager.